# Discrete fourier transform in different forms

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis

For the discrete Fourier transform, it is defined by

$$f(k)=\sum_{s_i}\exp(-iks)\phi(s).~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(ds-1)$$
here $s_i=-(N-1)/2,-(N-2)/2,.....(N-1)/2$.

For convenience, we also add the continuous Fourier transform

$$f(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-iks)\phi(s)ds~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(cn-1)$$

It can be seen that for the discrete case,  the integral of the right-hand side of Eq.~(cn-1) is chosen at some special point, i.e.,  $s_i=-(N-1)/2,-(N-2)/2,.....(N-1)/2$. If you take $N\to \infty$, the above two formulas should consistent with each other.

While for the inverse discrete Fourier transform, it reads

$$\phi(s)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k_i}\exp(iks)f(k),~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(ds-2)$$
where $k_i=-\frac{2\pi}{N}\frac{N-1}{2},......\frac{2\pi}{N}\frac{N-1}{2}$. Let $N\to \infty$, Eq.~(ds-2) can be shown by
$$\phi(s)=?\frac{1}{N}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp(iks)f(k)dk~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(ds-3)$$
I believe Eq.~(ds-3) is wrong if you let $N\to \infty$.

I see that in some books, they use

$$\phi(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp(iks)f(k)dk~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(ds-4)$$

Question 1):   how to understand the equation (ds-3) and (ds-4). Why $N$ should be replaced by $2\pi$?

Question 2):  If N is finite, we can use Eq.~(ds-1) for the discrete Fourier transform, and the inverse is given by (ds-2). While, for the discrete case, if $N\to \infty$, how can I get the inverse discrete Fourier transform?  Can we use Eq.~(ds-2)?  But If $N\to \infty$,  it seems that Eq.~(ds-2) is not correct.

Question 3)  If $N\to \infty$, can we use the continuous Fourier transform, i.e., $$\phi(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(iks)f(k)dk~~~~~~~~(cn-2)$$
to estimate Eq.~($ds-2$)? It seems that Eq.($ds-4$) is different from Eq.~(cn-2). Is there some relation between  Eq.~(ds-4) and  Eq.(cn-2).

Question 4, whih formula is the discrete inverse Fourier tansfom in the limit of $N\to \infty$?

Any suggestions or related URL or books are welcome!  Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing up Fourier transforms on the circle/unitary group $S^1 = U(1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. The dual group of $U(1)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, hence the Fourier transform on $U(1)$  produces a Fourier series. Thus the inverse discrete Fourier transform _sums_ over $k$; the integral does not make sense.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher    https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/an-introduction-to-the-discrete-fourier-transform/             they also use Eq(ds-4) as the inverse discrete Fourier transform

Comment: Eq.1 and Eq.2  in the above url.  This is the first time I use the discrete fourier transform. Usually, I just the continuous form, i.e., the integral cn-1 and cn-2

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher   Maybe there is a integral for such case. For example, if you let $N\to infty$, there is no N any more.  So you cannot sum over k. For me, i did not know how to sum k when $N\to infty$.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher   It seems that when $N\to \infty$, Eq. (ds-1) is called discrete time Fourier transform

Comment: Isn‘t this more related to math.SE? Or is the OP looking for a way to understand specifically in mathematica?

Comment: @morbo   I am new  and I am not allowed to ask queation in Math.SE.